# Redirect the Mysites request to another site in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, iis, redirect, mysite

In SharePoint 2013, I am facing an issue when clicking on the **User id**, it redirects to MySite url:

```
https://mysites.example.com
```

Currently Mysites is not working and users are getting error message. Therefore is it possible to redirect any request that comes to mysites to another page (`underconstruction.aspx`)?

Comment: You should be able to hide the link via CSS. Use the developer tools (F12) to identify the object and then hide it. Could be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I come under such requirement I always select the simpler and easy way to achieve it.

- Just navigate to the MySite
- Edit the page
- Keep Content Editor WebPart
- Write following JS code `<script> window.location="http://UnderConstructionPageUrl"; </script>`
- Save the page

Once the MySite is ready just go and delete this `Content Editor WebPart`.

I wish it could help you or inform me if you need some other approach.

Comment: I don't have a mysite enabled on SharePoint, that is the reason why we don't want the error to appear and get it redirected to a page that says Under Constrction.